# Dojo Data Grid Adding Multiselect Column

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dgrid

I am using Dojo dgrid i have created a grid with multiple rows where each row has a checkbox. I would like to create a multiselect column for the check boxes. The column header should be a check box and when i check it all rows are automatically selected.

**Code** ([JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/devdarin/V2PBm/10/))

```
 function(parser, declare, OnDemandGrid, ColumnSet, Selection, selector,
        Keyboard, DijitRegistry, editor, ColumnHider) {
    parser.parse();

    var data = [ {
        Id : "1",
        idType : "Passport",
        idNumber : "12121545WWW"
    }, {
        Id : "2",
        idType : "Drivers Permit",
        idNumber : "11212154515 FF"
    }, {
        Id : "3",
        idType : "Electoral Identification",
        idNumber : "425123123121"
    } ];

    var columns = [ [ [ {
        label : "Id",
        field : "Id"
    }, editor({
        label : "",
        field : "select",
        sortable : false,
        autoSave : true
    }, "checkbox"), {
        field : "idType",
        label : "Identification Type"
    }, {
        field : "idNumber",
        label : "Identification Number"
    } ] ] ];

    var CustomGrid = declare([ OnDemandGrid, Selection, selector, Keyboard,
            editor, DijitRegistry, ColumnHider ]);

    var grid = new CustomGrid({
        columns : {

            col1 : {
                label : "Id",
                field : "Id",
                hidden : true
            },

            col2 : editor({
                label : "Select",
                field : "select",
                sortable : false,
                autosave : true
            }, "checkbox"),

            col3 : {
                label : "ID Type",
                field : "idType"
            },

            col4 : {
                label : "ID Number",
                field : "idNumber"
            }

        },
        "class" : "grid",
        allowSelectAll : true
    }, "grid");

    // grid.styleColumn("Id","display:none;");

    grid.renderArray(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `selector` is a function that should be used to generate column that contains exactly what you want. It should not be mixed to the grid, it should be used in the column definition instead:

`columns: {
selector: selector(),
}`

"Select All" checkbox is rendered automatically in header by the `selector` if the grid has `allowSelectAll` property set to `true`.
[Here is your updated code](http://jsfiddle.net/N65Pn/2/)